# Is there a alternative in Kotlin coroutines for RxJava's 'Single'?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I am trying to convert some RxJava code to use coroutines instead.

Here is an example of code to make an API call using `Single` in RxJava. What do I need to do to replicate that part of the functionality using coroutines?

```
 override fun getRegisteredDevicesList(
        headerStoreId: String,
        headerDeviceId: String,
        headerApplicationVersionNo: String,
        appId: String,
        storeId: String
    ): Single<Result<RegisteredDevicesListData>> {

        return deviceLocatorApiService.getRegisteredDevicesListFromServer(
            headerStoreId = headerStoreId,
            headerDeviceId = headerDeviceId,
            headerApplicationVersionNo = headerApplicationVersionNo,
            registeredDevicesListRequest = RegisteredDevicesListRequest(
                appId = appId,
                storeId = storeId
            )
        )
            .map { Result.withValue(it.toDomain()) }
            .onErrorReturn {
                Result.withError(
                    DeviceLocatorError(Utility.getNetworkErrorMessageFromThrowable(it), it)
                )
            }
    }
```

Someone suggested that I use `coroutineScopes`, but I'm struggling to implement it.

Answer (score 2):

Kotlin publishes a number of [Coroutines for reactive streams libraries](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/reactive/README.md) that already provide helper methods for converting RxJava code into coroutines code such as an [`await` method](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-rx2/kotlinx.coroutines.rx2/await.html) that transforms a `Single` into a suspending function (which is the equivalent in coroutines):

```
suspend fun getRegisteredDevicesListSuspending(
  headerStoreId: String,
  headerDeviceId: String,
  headerApplicationVersionNo: String,
  appId: String,
  storeId: String
): Result<RegisteredDevicesListData> {
  return getRegisteredDevicesList(
    headerStoreId,
    headerDeviceId,
    headerApplicationVersionNo,
    appId,
    storeId
  ).await() // Transforms your Single into a suspending method
}
```

Of course, if you want to go deeper and avoid usages of RxJava entirely, you can also use APIs like [`suspendCancellableCoroutine`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/suspend-cancellable-coroutine.html) to convert a callback based API directly into coroutines as explained in [this blog post](https://manuelvivo.dev/simplifying-apis-coroutines).